# How to develop an AI script

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pygame, game-engine, game-physics

I am amateur Programmer looking to develop a game. I've decided to use Python and pygame. (I know, there are better options out there, but I really don't know C++ or java that well.) The issue I'm having is that I really have no idea how to create a decent AI. I'm talking about the sort of AI that has monsters move this way at this point, use a bow and arrow at that point, and use a long-range magic attack at another point (yes, its a top-down 2-d fantasy game). I really don't understand how it makes those decisions and how you program it to make those decisions. I've looked around everywhere, and either the resource gets so technical that I can't understand it at all, or it gives me no information whatsoever. I'm hoping someone here can give me some clear suggestions, or at least point me to some decent resources. Right now my bots just sort of wander randomly around the screen...

Comment: This isn't constructive for the SO format - may I suggest you ask on programmers (which deals with more theory things) - SO is for specific problems, that may have specific solutions - your question does not I'm afraid - please do not hesitate to ask here after you hit a specific problem though :)

Comment: If you're interested, have a look at [this](https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/python-dungeon-crawler/) old project of mine. I don't know if it is runable in the moment (mabye you have to use a older revision), but it has a working AI as you describe in your question. Also, ensure to check out [roguebasin](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org), which has plenty of articles about AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556220782) is a great book about the topic. It has many examples included which are also explained in the book. The code is C++ but it's pretty straightforward to understand.

Here's a short description about the book taken from Amazon:

> "Programming Game AI by Example" provides a comprehensive and practical
>   introduction to the bread and butter AI techniques used by the game
>   development industry, leading the reader through the process of
>   designing, programming, and implementing intelligent agents for action
>   games using the C++ programming language. Techniques covered include
>   state- and goal-based behavior, inter-agent communication, individual
>   and group steering behaviors, team AI, graph theory, search, path
>   planning and optimization, triggers, scripting, scripted finite state
>   machines, perceptual modeling, goal evaluation, goal arbitration, and
>   fuzzy logic.

Comment: the author also has a website http://www.ai-junkie.com/ai-junkie.html

Answer (score 2):

basically its

- Default Behavior:Random Walk
- if player is within X distance: Melee Attack
- if player is within Y distance: Charge Player
- if player is within Z distance: Cast spell
- if player is outside range and MOB has agro move toward player

thats the extent of most AI... at least game AI

its too cpu intensive to do things like neural networks and machine learning for game mobs

you may want to look at fuzzy logic AI ... thats largely what i described up there but it can be more than one simultaneuosly

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will be useful for you. It's even in python.

http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs373/CourseRev/apr2012

Edit: Game AI's tend to be much less robust then most other ai's (since they tend to have a very limited amount of CPU time for each game tick). This still covers the basics that game AI's use.